# Inserting formula using VBA in Excel does not work

Tags: vba, excel

First of all, I have tried to look at all the other examples of adding a formula using VBA, and I think I have tried to apply all the answers in this code

```
Sub AddFormulas(SheetName As String)
    Dim i As Integer

    'Switch worksheet
    Set Wksht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)
    Wksht.Activate
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    i = 2
    While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))
        Wksht.Cells(i, 18).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A" & i & ";" & Wksht.Cells(1, 18) & "!$A:$A;1;FALSE);" & Chr(34) & "MISSING" & Chr(34) & ")"
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


End Sub
```

But still, it gives me this anoying error, that I can't interpret
[image]

If I change my line to

```
Wksht.Cells(i, 18) = "'IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A" & i & ";" & Wksht.Cells(1, 18) & "!$A:$A;1;FALSE);" & Chr(34) & "MISSING" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Then I get no error, and the correct formula is added, although as a text string

What is wrong, since it would not add what to me looks like a valid formula?

//V

Comment: You must use English version formulas when inserting them via VBA.  So `;` should be `,`.

Comment: You should use `.Formula` or `.Formulalocal` or `.Value` or `.Text` ... after `Wksht.Cells(x,x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Formula` property requires formulas to be written in English, i.e. English function names (not an issue here) and commas as separators rather than semi-colons.

So your statement should be:

```
Wksht.Cells(i, 18).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A" & i & "," & Wksht.Cells(1, 18) & "!$A:$A,1,FALSE)," & Chr(34) & "MISSING" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

---

If you don't mind having "portability" issues, you could also use the `FormulaLocal` property, i.e.

```
Wksht.Cells(i, 18).FormulaLocal = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A" & i & ";" & Wksht.Cells(1, 18) & "!$A:$A;1;FALSE);" & Chr(34) & "MISSING" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Comment: Thank you! @YowE3K this is why I also love SO.
Now I have learned something new and valuable I wasn't aware of before,

Answer (score 0):

Write the formula as it should be in Excel, select it and run the following code:

```
Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

    Dim strFormula  As String
    Dim strParenth  As String

    strParenth = """"

    strFormula = Selection.Formula
    strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

    strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
    Debug.Print strFormula

End Sub
```

It should print it as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is giving error becouse of this  `Wksht.Cells(1, 18)` part of line in this row `Wksht.Cells(i, 18).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A" & i & ";" & Wksht.Cells(1, 18) & "!$A:$A;1;FALSE);" & Chr(34) & "MISSING" & Chr(34) & ")"`. Make sure that `Wksht.Cells(1, 18)` really contains name of worksheet your are trying to address. If this cell is blank, you will receive previously mentioned error.